# Uncaught ReferenceError: org is not defined in CometD

Tags: jquery, cometd

I am about to setup sample chat application using CometD and download all the required files from [Git] (https://github.com/cometd/cometd/tree/master/cometd-javascript) !

When i try to run the application it says "**Uncaught ReferenceError: org is not defined** "

Can someone thru the light on this ?

my JS files are in following order

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/cometd/common/src/main/webapp/org/cometd/AckExtension.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/cometd/common/src/main/webapp/org/cometd/ReloadExtension.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/cometd/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/cometd/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/cometd/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.cometd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://myserver.com/cometd/jquery/src/main/webapp/jquery/jquery.cometd-reload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        contextPath: location.href.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]*/, '').replace(/\/jquery-examples\/.*$/, '')
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `<script>` that loads the `org/cometd.js` file.

I recommend that you either use an archetype as explained in the [primer](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/primer.html), or that you follow the [tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/).

Comment: Hey sbordet , i have the org/cometd.js but i get the same error.

Comment: Have you followed the primer and the tutorials and they don't work ?

Comment: I followed and downloaded the cometd-javascript and running the chat example... still cant figure out the error. i tried including the cometd-namespace.js as well.